# How to exclude some pattern when doing a search in MC?

Tags: midnight-commander

In Midnight Commander, is it possible to exclude some directories/patterns/... when doing search? (`M-?`) I'm specifically interested in skipping the `.hg` subdirectory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the "[Misc]" section of your ~/.mc/ini file, you can specify the directories you wish to skip in the "find_ignore_dirs" setting.

To specify multiple directories, use a colon (":") as the delimiter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems only to work for absolute dirs, but that's still something. And your hint helped me to start further research, which seems to show that some cutting-edge versions of mc seem to have this feature boosted a bit.

Comment: It definitely would be nice if this could be a part of the user interface since changes to configuration files tend to be more permanent.  Thanks for the update!

Comment: Is there a way to ignore files?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, I wasn't able to find more on the web, so I downloaded the source and read the relevant parts.

The way to do this now is look for the `[FindFile]` section. If it does not exist, create it. You need to edit it so it reads (to ignore `.git` and `.hg` directories):

```
[FindFile]
ignore_dirs_enable=true
ignore_dirs=.git:.hg
```